# git push and git push heroku master in one step

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Is there a way to execute `git push` and `git push heroku master` all in one line on the command prompt?

It is cumbersome and time-consuming to go `git push`, wait, wait, then `git push heroku master`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's two ways:

In your shell (you don't have to wait, it'll execute these both one after the other):

```
git push origin master && git push heroku master
```

If you install the [hub gem](https://github.com/defunkt/hub), you can push to origin and heroku (and more), like so:

```
hub push origin,heroku master
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just open a second shell? You can run `git push` in one shell, and `git push heroku master` in the other.